# Make `less` exit after last page or `more` interpret colors

Tags: macos, less, bsd, pager, more

In a script, I’m doing a `git diff` that I want to quickly page through. When I’m finished, the pager will exit and the script will continue.

`more` is great for the task, because I can <kbd>space</kbd> through it and it will exit at the end of the file. Unfortunately, instead of the diff colours it shows the control characters.

`less` shows the colours just fine, but when reaching the end of the file it does not exit, <kbd>q</kbd> is needed.

How do I get both colour support and exiting on last <kbd>space</kbd>? No external tools can be added, only what comes with a default macOS installation.

Comment: Add -E to less.

Comment: @llua Thank you. If you want to add that as an answer, I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From `less`’s `man` page:

```
-E or --QUIT-AT-EOF
          Causes less to automatically exit the first time it reaches end-of-file.
```